# The $0^{\rm th}$ prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was performing some calculations with the online version of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com), when I was presented with a formula containing the number $p_0$. Since Wolfram defines $p_n$ as the $n^{\rm th}$ prime, I was naturally intrigued as to what Wolfram meant by $p_0$. Inputting `Prime[0]` into Wolfram, I was presented with the following expression:

$$
p_0 = -\sqrt{10} \lfloor\sqrt{10} \alpha\rfloor + \lfloor 10^1 \alpha\rfloor, 
$$

where

$$
\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_k}{10^{2^k}}.
$$

What does this mean, where does it come from and why does it make sense to talk about a $0^{\rm th}$ prime number?

Comment: I think that $p_0=p(0)=1$ could also be the value of the ordinary [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function), and not necessarily the $0$-th prime.

Comment: I think Wolfram Alpha is messing with you, since $\alpha<\frac{2}{90}$ so $p_0=0$.

Comment: Similarly strange things if you keep messing with Prime[n] for other unusual values of $n$, for example $Prime[-1]$ and $Prime[1.5]$.  My expectation is that no effort was made to make sure that input variables make sense and instead of outputting a number, they output one of the various series representations of the $n$'th prime number despite such a series representation not necessarily making sense for the input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking at a nonsensical circular definition.

$\alpha$ is a number that contains every prime by adding sufficiently shifted base 10 numbers. E.g.:

$\alpha = 0.02030005\ldots$

The expression above just extracts the primes by unshifting (multiplying by a power of 10) and flooring, subtracting the previous terms.

This expression results from plugging in $n = 0$ into the formula, leading to a non-sensical result (essentially a domain error).

Comment: Great explanation. Any idea why Wolfram would implement `Prime[n]` like this (instead of a table of primes, f.ex.)?

Comment: WolframAlpha probably isn't implementing it this way in general. (Although this is really just a "math" way to create a table in a single number.)

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_i}{10^{2^i}}$ then we can definitely get the values of $p_i$ back out by computing:

$$p_i=\left\lfloor 10^{2^i}\alpha\right\rfloor-10^{2^{i-1}}\left\lfloor 10^{2^{i-1}}\alpha\right\rfloor$$

This is just saying that we are encoding $p_i$ in the digits of $\alpha.$ It is essentially a silly formula, which would let you compute $p_{\sqrt{2}}$ and $p_{-\pi}$, but has no actual numeric use.

In particular, the choice of base $10$ is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Is there a good mathematical basis for such a definition? Is it useful in some cases? Why was such a formula chosen if $p_i$ obviously makes no sense for $i$ not in $\mathbb{N^+}$?

Comment: No, there is really no use at all.